# Arabic punctuation appearing in incorrect positions on live DigitalOcean server but fine on XAMPP localhost

Tags: php, html, arabic, punctuation

The text has one full stop and two commas and appears fine on my localhost (second sentence in bold)

> يمكن للزبون استبدال المنتج خلال ثلاثة أيام من تاريخ الشراء، ولا يوجد استرجاع للمبالغ النقدية. **في حال عدم استلام الطلب خلال شهر من بعد موعد الاستلام، سيتم عرضه للبيع والمبلغ لا يسترجع**

But on live server

> .يمكن للزبون استبدال المنتج خلال ثلاثة ايام من تاريخ الشراء ولا يوجد استرجاع للمبالغ النقدية , **في حال عدم استلام الطلب خلال شهر من بعد موعد الاستلام سيتم عرضه للبيع و المبلغ لايسترجع**

All of the marks are in wrong positions and one of the commas disappears too.

I have tried changing to "direction: rtl" and "unicode-bidi" and they either do nothing or make it worse.

It is a PHP Yii2 project. I am not sure if the issue is with server config itself or maybe different PHP versions. Localhost is PHP 7.4.6 and server is PHP 7.4.27.

Any help is appreciated as this is affecting our client.

Edit:

```
<div class='column' style="float:left; width:auto;max-width:820px; margin-right:40px; margin-bottom:20px;">
        <?php echo "<h4><b>Terms & Conditions:</b></h4>"; ?>

        <div class='column' style='border:solid 1px #b5b5b5; border-radius:4px;padding:10px;max-height:120px;overflow-wrap: break-word;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;'>
        <?php
            echo $model->terms_and_conditions;
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing this text? On a web page? Not enough information to really help. Could be database level, DOM, etc. Guess I'm asking where does it go wrong?

Comment: HTML web page. Echoed text. Frontend. Nothing backend.

Comment: And if you look at the source, the actual source is different between the two environments? This is static HTML? Trying to understand the PHP component.

Comment: We need to see some code and raw data - you'll need to provide us a [mre] of the issue, please. If you can genuinely verify that you have the _exact_ same code and the _exact_ same content on both copies of the site then it's probably some sort of config issue (although I'm struggling to think what it would be which could cause this particular issue, tbh). But at the moment you've provided no evidence either way. I'd suggest it's more likely that the content is simply different in each site.

Comment: The sourse is MySQL database. The text is correct in both local and live server databases. The content is the same. Sure I will add some code and screenshots to the post.

Comment: If the text is genuinel identical in both DBs it's hard to see why it would be altered in this way before being shown on the page. Best I can think of is some kind of encoding mismatch, meaning it's interpreting some character codes incorrectly.

Comment: I'd start by checking what Charset (if any) is contained in the Content-Type header on each of those systems.

Comment: Well last update to question makes me think mysql configuration differences, maybe try a `set names utf8`. Or you need to compare the data better, how was it migrated? Does this controller code do some sort of escaping? That would be another place to focus.